# JQuery.on() click listener not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick, event-handling, jquery-events

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<table class="table table-hover js-integrations js-radio-rows">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Modified Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Start load by ajax -->
            <tr class="clickable">
                <td class="js-integration-option">
                    <input type="radio" value="20" name="integration_id" class="pseudo-radio sr-only">
                    <label class="icon-lg" for="http-radio"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img align="absmiddle" src="imglocation" />
                    Some Title
                    <span class="file-size">
                        (50kb)
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Owner Le Own
                </td>
                <td>
                    Date
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- End load by ajax -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I have this piece of jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('here1');
    jQuery('.js-radio-rows').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        console.log('here2');
    });
});
```

When I click on the clickable row, `console.log('here2')` does not fire. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Could it be because the rows are loaded by ajax? This happens long after document ready is called, since it depends on something else that is clicked.

Comment: Are you adding the class `js-radio-rows` dynamically or in ajax function call?

Comment: this seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/2nph69tz/ maby you have a styling problem

Comment: try handling directly to the document, try with `jQuery(document).on('click', '.js-radio-rows tr', function()...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.js-radio-rows` table is not available on document.ready event, this will not work. Try setting `document` as delegate for the event:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.js-radio-rows tr', function() {
    console.log('here2');
});
```

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner. When I read the answer it made sense. It can't use `.js-radio-rows` as delegate, because it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('here1');            
    $('.js-radio-rows tr').on('click', function () {
        console.log('here2');
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('here1');            
    $(document).on('click', '.js-radio-rows tr', function () {
        console.log('here2');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: second bit works, however anser already provided by kapantzak. Thanks for input though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log('here1');

    $('.js-radio-rows').on('click', 'tr', function() {

        console.log('here2');

    });

 })
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
        <style>   
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <table class="table table-hover js-integrations js-radio-rows">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Modified Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Start load by ajax -->
            <tr class="clickable">
                <td class="js-integration-option">
                    <input type="radio" value="20" name="integration_id" class="pseudo-radio sr-only">
                    <label class="icon-lg" for="http-radio"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img align="absmiddle" src="imglocation" />
                    Some Title
                    <span class="file-size">
                        (50kb)
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Owner Le Own
                </td>
                <td>
                    Date
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- End load by ajax -->
    </tbody>
</table>
       

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    console.log('here1');
    
    $('.js-radio-rows').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        
        console.log('here2');
        
    });
      
 })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you changed?